# Please help with striped binary reverse

Tags: ida, disassembly, elf, system-call, heap

Not so long ago I was engaged in reverse and pwn, I came across such a task
This is a normal task with a vulnerability on the heap, but it is striped and I don’t understand where which functions are
I tried to track system calls with strace, but I still don't understand what and how it works

Maybe you can help me with something?

This is my first time on the forum and I don't know how to attach files...

Maybe you can tell me how it is more convenient to track all the syscalls and understand what is where